# C# WIA set resolution doesnt increase resolution instead increases image width and height. in C#

Tags: c#, resolution, wia

i am trying to scan a document/photo using WIA (Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0) in C#, but when i increase resolution it doesn't increase the resolution instead increases width and height of the image, but the resolution stays the same. 
(Default dpi of the scanner is 75 dpi)
**ImageFile** variable always has 96 dpi.

eg.
if at default dpi 75, image has width and height of 100 then
if i set dpi to 150, image will have width and height of 200.
but the resulting ImageFile always has 96 dpi regardless of dpi i have set.

```
            WIA.ImageFile img = null;
            WIA.Item Item = WiaDev.Items[1] as WIA.Item;


            try
            {
                Item.Properties.get_Item("4104").set_Value(24);
                Item.Properties.get_Item("6146").set_Value(1);


                double OrigResolution = Convert.ToDouble(Item.Properties["6147"].get_Value().ToString());
                double ResDiff = 0.0;
                int width = 0, height = 0;
                if (OrigResolution < dpi)
                {
                    ResDiff = 150 / OrigResolution;
                    width = (int)Math.Floor((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Properties["6151"].get_Value().ToString()) * ResDiff));
                    height = (int)Math.Floor((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Properties["6152"].get_Value().ToString()) * ResDiff));

                    Item.Properties["6149"].set_Value(0);
                    Item.Properties["6150"].set_Value(0);

                    Item.Properties.get_Item("6147").set_Value(dpi.ToString("0.0"));
                    Item.Properties.get_Item("6148").set_Value(dpi.ToString("0.0"));

                    Item.Properties["6151"].set_Value(width);
                    Item.Properties["6152"].set_Value(height);
                }

                img = (ImageFile)WiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(Item, WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, false);
                img.SaveFile("D:\\Test.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample example , you can try according to it

```
private void setItem(IItem item, object property, object value)
   {
       WIA.Property aProperty = item.Properties.get_Item(ref property);
       aProperty.set_Value(ref value);
   }



   internal bool Scan(bool flatBed)
   {

       WIA.DeviceManager manager = new DeviceManager();
       bool result = false;
       object something = 1;
       object somethingElse;
       WIA.Device scanner = manager.DeviceInfos.get_Item(ref something).Connect();
       IItem item = scanner.Items[1];
      setItem(item, "6146", 4);
       setItem(item, "6147", 200);
       setItem(item, "6148", 200);
       setItem(item, "6151", 200 * 8.5);
       setItem(item, "6152", 200 * 11);
   }
```

The first setItem is the color [4 black and white, 2 grayscale, 1 color, 0 unspecified]
The second is horizontal resolution.
The third is veritcal resolution.
The fourth is horizontal scanning area.
The fifth is vertical scanning area.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but not working, same result 
here is image [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/a1d5b4b4cf.jpg).